# Fetching friends for someone with a lot of friends returns a 500

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch the friends of a user who has a lot of them (> 8,000). I have the correct token (which I verifed in the Debug section of the Facebook Graph Explorer) and I'm issuing the standard Graph request in the Explorer:

`/<fbid>?fields=friends`

But the request fails with a 500 in my code and with a "Request failed" in the Facebook Explorer.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There should be no users with more than 5,000 friends, the system simply can't handle more than that and if it happened somehow i think a failure is likely expected - are you sure there's 8000?
Does it work when you request subsets? (e.g. /<user>/friends?limit=1000 ) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because the system is unable to handle the request. Try to use *limit* and *offset* parameters in the query:

```
/<fbid>/friends?offset=0&limit=500
```